# imap fetch_body outputs incorrect html

Tags: php, html, gmail, imap

The code below outputs incorrect html and insert some junk chars in between. I think the solution will be base conversion. But I can't figure out which base.

```
<?php
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}[Gmail]/Sent Mail';
$username = '...@gmail.com';
$password = '*****';
$sent = imap_open($hostname, $username, $password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
$emails   = imap_search($sent, 'SUBJECT "Part"');

if ($emails)
{
    foreach ($emails as $email_number)
    {
        $message = imap_body($sent, $email_number,1.2);
        echo $message;
    }
}
imap_close($sent);

?>
```

**OUTPUT HTML**

```
<td colspan="3D&quot;2&quot;" 
st="yle=3D&quot;
border-color:rgb(204,204,20=" 4);
border-width:0px="" 0px="" 1px="" 1px;
font-family:ari="al;
color:rgb(255,255,255);
background-color:rgb(123,186,0=" );
text-align:center;
width:100px"="">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you'll want to decode your output before displaying it using `quoted_printable_decode()` specifically like so:

```
foreach ($emails as $email_number)
{
    $message = imap_body($sent, $email_number,1.2);
    echo quoted_printable_decode($message);
}
```

Read more about this function here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php

Note: `imap_qprint()` performs identically and can be used as well.

Comment: I edited my answer to make note of that, but I always like to choose the function that has a more descriptive name and does not require dependencies.

Comment: I agree but the context of this question concerns the use of the `imap_` library, either way this should be the proper resolution anyway.

Answer (score 1):

IMAP is just the transport protocol of the mail. The mail message itself can have an inherent structure in MIME format, e.g. a typical HTML message with an attachment will have the following structure:

```
mail
|- multipart/mixed
|  |- multipart/alternative
|     |- text/plain - plain text content
|     |- text/html  - HTML content
|- application/octet-stream - the attachment
```

Each of the leaf parts (e.g. contents and attachment) might have a content-transfer-encoding, typically quoted-printable, base64 or sometimes binary. The text parts might also have a character set (defined within the content-type header), e.g. utf-8, iso-8859-1 etc. Also there might be text parts which are used as attachment, they have content-disposition header set to 'attachment'.

To display the text of the mail you have to first find the relevant content part(s), then decode the content-transfer-encoding and then convert the content from the given character set in the you need for output. The IMAP library has support for most of the necessary operations, but there seems to be no simple way to get the content in a form you need, e.g. you have to call all the functions for parsing structure, decoding and converting yourself.

Comment: I am using text/html. "1.2" in this line.  $message = imap_body($sent, $email_number,1.2);   Your answer is informative. Thanks for it. My problem resolved by using quoted_printable_decode()

Comment: Your particular problem was indeed fixed by calling quoted_printable_decode. What you have not fixed is that the same message could easily use e.g. base64 encoding. It will still be a completely valid e-mail, but your code will fail to work properly, which is why Steffen took the time to add his elaborate answer.